# I want to be interviewed and find a paid job: are there better alternatives to applying on web sites?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, new-job, job-change

I know that the question seems to broad so I'll clarify it right now.

A little background: I live in Italy and I finished school this year, at July 6.
Since then, I started immediately to look for a job. I registered in a lot of online sites, wrote lots of curriculums (job search sites usually have a guided template so I had to do them a lot of times) and applied for over a hundred job offers.
I don't have particular preferences, I just need money, for now, and I know that I cannot tell this to a possible employer.
For what it counts, I graduated in computer science.

The problem : even if I applied for so many offers, I got invited only in a job interview, and it went pretty bad.

Now I'm currently working as an intern, but I'm not satisfied with this opportunity ( I consider it a waste of time, since I learn very little over 8 hours of work ). I want to search for something better but I don't want to waste more time on web sites that will definetely not help me.

I thought that I could go directly on some workplaces I find on the internet and give my CV by hand.

Is this a possible solution?
How can I, at least, get involved in a job interview?

Many thanks to everyone.

Comment: They only let me put my CV on their site so it's not that useful

Comment: The basics of job searching is to apply for open positions that suit your experience, match your requirements by writing a highly marketable (but correct) resume and an amazing cover letter. But covering that subject in detail is not really possible on a Q&A site. Note that [showing up without an appointment](http://www.askamanager.org/2009/03/should-show-up-without-appointment.html) is *never* a good idea. That's common advice that's horribly out of date and has never been appropriate for office jobs.

Comment: You need to get your resume reviewed by someone knowledgeable in job searching. If your college does not offer that service, ask around your friends, relatives, former professors...

Comment: Remember that the Italian job market is oversaturated right now, so keep trying and don't give up, you'll eventually find something that suits you.

Comment: Rejected a lot is normal more so if you're just out of collage and have zero experience. This is my tips call your friend that already got a job ask them if their company is hiring or not, believe it or not the chance you get interview is way higher if you have friend that can vouch for you.

Comment: @A.Danzi - don't underestimate your internship, while you may not learn much, you are gaining experience (even if just on paper), which will help you in future job hunt. Other than that, get a specialist to look over your CV and motivational letter. Even if you have to pay for something like this, it can be really worth it.

Comment: @kirie It would be ok to be rejected for me, but, at least, I would like to do a job interview. 1 interview every 100 job requests is pretty bad imo.
Anyway I'll listen to you all so many thanks for the help

Comment: Wait hang on. You graduated in CS in Europe months ago but still haven't found work? You are doing something dramatically wrong and my guess is that applying for over a hundred companies has a lot to do with it. Quality is more important than quantity, which should have already become apparent to you after you got only a *single* interview. I'd suggest asking for feedback in [chat] or looking at other online resources or fora to help you with specific advice or to evaluate your application materials.

Comment: @kirie A 99% pre-screening rejection rate is most certainly not normal though, even in Italy's horrendous job market.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned that you had an interview and that it went badly. Can you remember some specific problems which you might be able to improve? Maybe some of them also apply to your application and you can enhance it as well.

Also try to find a friend with a bit more experience and let him help you with your application. You will have much better chances if your letter is written properly.

Another possibility would be job fairs. There you get in direct contact with your potential new employer and they often like it if you can hand them your CV directly.

As a side note: Yes, your internship might be boring but future employers like to see that you didn't sit on your lazy butt during the job search time. It is also a chance for a nice letter of recommendation or they might hire you directly for a permanent job.

Comment: Yes, this weekend I'll be at a job fair so I hope It'll be helpful. Will hand them my CV directly as you said.
Anyway my internship is not only boring, but is almost useless since the person that follows us (we are 5 currently) is, for most of the time, absent.

Comment: Don't see your internship that way : also see it as a "line on your CV", with possibly a reference letter. If you get your current company to say you were a smart, hard-working intern, it will also help you get a job.